# Превращение часть повторяющегося кода в процедуру. WinAPI и memcpy

Tags: c++, winapi

В учебных целях создавал и делал запись имён зверей в heap в потоке.

```cpp
void heap_alloc(char* source_string, HANDLE hHeap, const std::string assign_string)
{
    const int alloc_size = 20 * sizeof(char);
    
    source_string = (char*) HeapAlloc(
        hHeap,
        NULL,
        alloc_size
    );
    if (source_string == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Heap allocation failed." << std::endl;
    }
    memcpy(source_string, assign_string.c_str(), assign_string.size() + 1);
}
```

И вызов:

```cpp
heap_alloc(arr_animal[0], hHeap, "fly");
```

Выдаёт ошибку, когда к этой облости памяти обращаюся, с сообщением: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xCDCDCDCD.

Рабочий код, который превращал в процедуру:

```cpp
arr_animal[1] = (char*) HeapAlloc(hHeap, NULL, alloc_size);
if (arr_animal[1] == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Heap allocation failed." << std::endl;
    return GetLastError();
}
memcpy(arr_animal[1], "spider", 7);
```

Comment: В такую процедуру надо передавать адрес указателя, который в ней будет модифицирован результатом вызова `HeapAlloc()`

Comment: ¿А вас не смущает, что `alloc_size` никак не зависит от длины входящей строки? ¿Или что значение, присвоенное `source_string`, будет потеряно при выходе ее из области видимости?

Comment: @user7860670 Это из старого кода. Спасибо за замечание, поправлю.

Comment: @avp какой указатель нужно передавать? Просто ... HANDLE - дескриптор, предназначенный для описания различных объектов. На самом деле этот тип представляет собой ни что иное, как указатель на void, т.е. как бы на любой тип.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что при вызове `heap_alloc(()` надо передать указатель на `arr_animal[0]`. Тогда начало самой процедуры будет `void heap_alloc(char **source_string, HANDLE hHeap, const std::string assign_string)` и в ней вместо `source_string` надо будет обращаться к `*source_string`

Comment: @avp Спасибо большое. Будете писать ответ(оставите место для кода и я вставля его) или я напишу его?

Comment: Конечно сами пишите

Answer (score 1):

avp в комментариях дал правильный ответ:

при вызове `heap_alloc()` надо передать указатель на `arr_animal[0]`. Тогда начало самой процедуры будет `void heap_alloc(char **source_string, HANDLE hHeap, const std::string assign_string)` и в ней вместо `source_string` надо будет обращаться к `*source_string`.

В итоге код процедуры получился таким:

```cpp
void heap_alloc(char** source_string, HANDLE hHeap, const std::string assign_string)
{
    const int alloc_size = (assign_string.size() + 1) * sizeof(char);
    
    *source_string = (char*) HeapAlloc(
        hHeap,
        NULL,
        alloc_size
    );
    if (*source_string == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Heap allocation failed for " << assign_string << std::endl;
    }
    memcpy(*source_string, assign_string.c_str(), assign_string.size() + 1);
}
```

А код вызова процедуры будет:

```cpp
heap_alloc(&arr_animal[0], hHeap, "fly");
```